# Prove integration by parts identity starting from $\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f(x)f'(y)\frac{d}{dx}\log|x-y|dxdy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

How does one prove the following identity?
$$\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f(x)f'(y)\frac{d}{dx}\log|x-y|dxdy
$$ $$=-f(0)\int_{0}^\infty f'(y)\log y\,dy-\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f'(x)f'(y)\log|x-y|dxdy$$
where $f$ is a smooth function.
I suppose integration by parts is used, but I don't understand where the boundary term comes from.

Comment: motivation for this?

Comment: There seems to be a $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)log\vert{x-y}\vert$ that disappears in the RHS somehow.

Comment: @crystal_math The motivation is an identity about the Hilbert transform https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381740/integration-by-parts-with-hilbert-transform/381745#381745

Comment: @Omar What do you mean?

Comment: My (incomplete) solution is: start from LHS, take $f'(y)$ outside the inner integral since it is not a function of $x$ and so is treated as a constant, then do integration by parts for the inner integral. You get $$ [f(x)log{\vert x-y \vert}]_0^\infty -\int_0^\infty f'(x)log{\vert x-y \vert}dx $$

Comment: Then, the result will be $$ \int_0^\infty f'(y) \biggl( [f(x)log|x−y|]_0^\infty−\int_0^\infty f′(x)log|x−y|dx \biggr) dy $$ Which then equals $$\int_0^\infty f'(y) \lim_{x \to \infty} \Bigl( f(x)log|x−y| \Bigr) dy - f(0)\int_0^{\infty} f'(y)log(y)dy - \int_0^\infty f'(y)f'(x)log|x−y|dx  dy $$ Now I don't know how the first term evaluates to zero